# Why android toast message always show appname:message in my app?

Tags: android, toast

My android toast message always show "appname:message" in my app.
For example:my app name is "Chat", when I use
`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
It always show
`Chat:test`
toast on my phone, that's very odd.
How to fix it? Thanks.
PS:It's only happens on my phone(android8.1), android 5.1 7.0 and 8.0 not happen.

Comment: Try changing `getActivity()` to `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @statosdotcom not work for me. same as `getActivity()`

Comment: The same happens on emulator? Same happens if you compile with another SDK API? Also, please, edit your question, if possible, giving more details about your code.

Comment: @statosdotcom It's not happen on emulator(android8.0). But happens on my phone (android8.1), let me try other phones.

Comment: that is not your app, but your device causing it. You can't fix it. Some firmwares show the app name which is showing the toast.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko OK, I got it, thanks